# How can i achieve a grid/table layout with automatic column count

Tags: flutter

I have a collection of `Text` Elements, and i would like to display them in columns, but such that Flutter determins the number of columns automatically based on the content and available space. Sort of like Wrap, but by placing the elements direktly underneath each other.
Is there a Layout that can do that?

Sort of like this:

```
Lorem ipsum      dolor      sit 
amet  consetetur sadipscing elitr 
sed   diam       nonumy
```

Comment: Seems impossible. How can Flutter decide how many items to run in a single row, is it based on the first X items that fits into the first row? After that, will the items in the second row forced to be aligned with the items in the first line? What if there are widgets that need more width so that it can't fit X items in the second row? Will the number of columns reduced? But doesn't that mean the last item that was on first row will now be in the second row, and then a recalculation would be needed, and the previous problem could happen again?

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could use a GridView.count(). But you have to specify the cross axis (<---->) count. It can't be automatic.